# Pick Version with Branchname as Classifier with Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I am evaluating gradle for our project. We have multiple small project that contain small util libraries. Most projects are in an extra repository and cannot use a shared buildscript. 
When working across multiple project the same feature branch is used. I already managed to get gradle to put the branchname into the created maven artifact as classifier. 
For our continous integration it would be really helpful to resolve a dependency to such a library to the one using its own branch name if it exists. If it doesn't it should fallback to the normal declared version.

I managed to change the versions via resolutionStrategy.eachDependency but I couldn't find a way to implement the fallback if no version for this branch exists.

Is there any way this can be achived?

Regards, 
arne

Comment: Any chance you remember how you added the branchname to the artifact name as classifier?

Comment: @KevinM Sry, for replying so late. Didn't find our old code. And it was with an old version of gradle so, so not sure if it would still work. I would look for a versioning plugin like https://github.com/nemerosa/versioning which can handle this. Didn't test this one, but looks quite good.

Comment: Thanks. After I wrote the comment, I dug deeper into the plugin we're using called Axion. It has the ability to add the branch name into the version file. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to write some code to achieve this. For example, you could copy the configuration, set classifiers for the copied configuration via `resolutionStrategy.eachDependency`, resolve the copied configuration via `configuration.resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration`, check which dependencies could be resolved, and then choose classifiers for the original configuration accordingly (again via `resolutionStrategy.eachDependency`). The best place to do all of this is in `configuration.incoming.beforeResolve`.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks a lot!! I have another problem with my build but I think this is a different topic so I posted it as a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784643/incremental-compile-in-gradle-not-working-when-using-file-from-classpath Can you give me a hint, how to solve this?