# Incremental Compile in Gradle not working when using file from classpath

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, incremental-build

I am trying to build some kind of support for a maven-like dependency-management for our project. 
For this I add the pom I want to inherit from as a classpath dependency in the buildscript. I wrote a plugin that adds a task "inherit" that takes a file as Input and parses it and puts the dependencies from that pom into a map. The task is started in the apply method of the plugin where I get the pom from the classpath.

```
static class InheritDependencyTask extends DefaultTask {

    @InputFile
    File pomForInheritance

   @Input
   def dependencyMap

    @TaskAction
    public void processPom(){

        def parsedPom = new XmlSlurper().parse(pomForInheritance)
        parsedPom.dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.each { dependency ->
            def key = dependency.groupId.text() + ":" + dependency.artifactId.text()
            String version = dependency.version.text()

            if (version.contains("\$")) {
                String propertyKey = version.replace("\${", "").replace('}', '')
                version = parsedPom.properties.getAt(propertyKey)
            }
            dependencyMap.put(key, version)
        }
    }

}
```

In the apply method of the plugin I add the task and make compile depend on it with:

```
project.compileJava.dependsOn("inherit")
           project.task("inherit", type: InheritDependencyTask){
                dependencyMap =  project.dependencyMap
                pomForInheritance = project.buildscript.configurations.classpath.find { File dependency -> (dependency.name.contains(MY_ARTIFACT_ID) )}
            }
```

At some other point I loop through my dependencies and change the versions according to the ones I got from the pom.

This all seems to work. But compileJava is never up to date. It always has to recompile. Am I doing something wrong or is gradle not able see that the classpath-file didn't change?

Regards, 
arne

Comment: Running with `--info` will tell you why `compileJava` is out-of-date. I don't understand why you'd want to use a POM for declaring the dependencies of a Gradle build, but that's another topic.

Comment: ok. thanks I will check that. There are two reasons why I would like to use a pom. First: I can have maven projects and gradle projects sharing configurations and I don't need to migrate everyting at once. Second: I don't loose the ability to build when I am offline since the poms are cached. This wouldn't work if I apply a start script from some url or am I mistaken? I need to share this configuration between projects in different repositories

Comment: I had refresh-dependencies as a parameter for running the task. Maybe it was that. Later I added another task with the same problem. This time the output was altered which forced it to rerun the task. This was not shown with info though. @PeterNiederwieser Can you hint me to a post where I can read about a hybrid maven/gradle setup? Using the pom is not something I really want to do. But it seemed like a good idea to me.