# Set classifier dynamically with Gradle

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up our continuous integration to build feature branches. I've modified our Gradle plugin to upload our library project artifacts to Nexus with the branch name as the classifier. However I can't find a way to change projects that depend on those libraries to set the classifier dynamically.

I've tried

```
project.configurations.all { config ->
    conf.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        details.useTarget("${details.requested.group}:${details.requested.name}:${details.requested.version}:${branch_name}")
        println "${details.target}"
    }
}
```

but the println shows that the target hasn't been updated with the classifier. If I dynamically change the name rather than using classifiers it works.

Is it possible to set the classifier dynamically and if so how?

A similar question has been answered previously which suggests doing it the way I've been attempting:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22780023/3209486

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to use `DependencyResolveDetails#useVersion` instead of `DependencyResolveDetails#useTarget`

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        String branch_name = "someBranchName"
        def newDependency = "$details.requested.group:$details.requested.name:$details.requested.version:$branch_name"
        println "Overriding details: $details --> $newDependency"
        details.useVersion newDependency
    }
}
```

Also you might want to add some checks so you don't override ***all*** dependencies, the above code would also replace the classifier for third party dependencies.  So if you had `gson` as a dependency you might see an error like this

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1:someBranchName.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1:someBranchName/gson-com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1:someBranchName.pom
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1:someBranchName/gson-com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1:someBranchName.jar
  Required by:
      com.example.stackoverflow.q34983255:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```